# Как определить с какого устройства пользователь зашёл на сайт?

Tags: php, javascript, html, экран

На сервере есть файл index.php и 2 папки, в одной мобильная версия сайта, во второй компьютерная.

Теперь вопрос, как мне определить, с какого устройства зашли на сайт, с компьютера или с телефона?

Если пользователь зашёл с пк, то грузиться сайт из папки 1.

А если с телефона, то с папки 2.

Просто хочу сделать десктопную и мобильную версию сайта.

Comment: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/  http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: В общем случае - никак.

Comment: `<a href="m...">Мобильная версия сайта</a>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Код очень простой:

```
function isMobile() { 

return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}

if(isMobile()){
    header("Location: Ваш сайт моб. версия");
}
else { Десктоп }
```

Comment: айпад так не определяет, пишет что дескоп, у моего айпада ни чем строка не отличается от макбука, если через сафари заходить

Answer (score 1):

Вот можно почитать http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php
 для определения операционной системы и на основании этих данных плюс разрешение экрана определить какую страницу загружать