# Можно ли сделать, чтобы мобильный CSS подгружался только на мобильных, а десктопный CSS - только на компьютерах?

Tags: php, css, pagespeed

Можно ли сделать, чтобы мобильный CSS подгружался только на мобильных, а десктопный CSS - только на компьютерах с целью повышения скорости загрузки?
По-сути, такое можно сделать на PHP, но вот в чем вопрос - есть ли подводные камни?
 Применяется ли такая практика
Давайте подискутируем. Все за и против.

Comment: Да, посмотрите сайт https://www.wildberries.ru/

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-for-desctop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 960px)">` и `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-for-mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 959px)">` Как пример, конечно же значения другие можно поставить. Все 3 варианта ответов в корне не правильные и не несут в себе нормального ответа, ибо тянуть на кой-то чёрт `js` вообще не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно примерно [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724723/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%91%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

```
<?php
function isMobile() {    
return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}

if(isMobile()): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="css/app.mobile.css">
<?php else: ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="css/app.desktop.css">
<?php endif ?>
```

Так же можно использовать функцию [`get_browser`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php), но для этого нужен [`browscap.ini`](http://browscap.org/)

Конечно если будет подменен `user_agent`, то это уже не ваши проблемы ;)

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы и нет) Если PHP правильно отследил устройство - все сработает, если же пользователь подменил user-agent - его проблема, не надо так делать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно подгружать css через js асинхронно, как вариант. В js можно получить размер экрана юзера, и, исходя из этого определить, какие стилевые файлы требуют подгрузки.